# MySQL foreign key constraint error when migrate in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have created 2 migration file which on file has a foreign key, when migrate, Laravel shows this error about
MySQL foreign key constraint error when migrate in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You run a migrate command,  first migration wants to create a relation but second table does nor exist,

Or you foreign key must be have same data type with related primary key in second table